# Installing multiple Quartz.NET services on one machine

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET 2.2.400.0 and am experiencing problems installing multiple instances on a single machine.

I am trying to amend the name of the instance via the configuration file (Quartz.Server.exe) as follows:

```
<quartz >
  <add key="quartz.checkConfiguration" value="false"/> 
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceName" value="CalSched"/> 
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceDisplayName" value="CalSched"/> 
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceDescription" value="CalSchedservice"/> 
</quartz>
```

When running Quartz.Server.exe install *without* the above, everything works perfectly.  When the service name is specified, the scheduler does not run.

I wondered if anybody would be able to shed any light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old thread. But I will put the answer here in case someone got same issue. When `<quartz>` tag (Quartz.Server.exe.config) is used, quartz will ignore configurations in quartz.config and therefore, this configuration line is ignored `quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames = ~/quartz_jobs.xml.` As a result, quartz won't read your job settings and won't run the job as expected.

So you need to move all your configuration to  tag. You need to add

```
<quartz >
  <add key="quartz.checkConfiguration" value="false"/> 
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceName" value="CalSched"/> 
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceDisplayName" value="CalSched"/> 
  <add key="quartz.server.serviceDescription" value="CalSchedservice"/>
  <!-- MUST ADD -->
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/quartz_jobs.xml" /> 
</quartz>
```

And it will work.

Comment: Brilliant - didn't ever find a solution to this. Works a treat.